# I need to use code from a json file as a src for an img in an html file

Tags: html, json, image, src

I am trying to make a chrome extension that displays a random image that will display as the new tab page. I have a folder full of pictures i want to include, all named numbers. I use a random number generator to decide which image will be displayed. I then store that chosen image in a variable, but i do not know how to put that json variable into my html file. Here's the json code that picks the image:

```
function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  let r = floor(random(90));
  let image = createImg('images/' + r + '.jpg');
  image.size(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  image.position(0, 0);
}
```

images is the folder that all my images are in

I have no clue how i should setup the HTML code. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you mean JS, not json, you should be able to put an `<img>` tag into your page like this:

```js
  let r = floor(random(90));
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'images/' + r + '.jpg';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
```